# Azure DevOps API - how to reference other pipeline as resource parameter

Tags: azure, azure-devops-rest-api

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline and want to reference other pipeline that my pipeline will fetch the artefacts from. I am struggling to find a way to actually do it over REST API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1 specifies there is a BuildResourceParameters or PipelineResourceParameters but I cannot find a way to get it to work.

For example:
Source pipeline A produces an artefact B in run C. I want to tell API to reference the artefact B from run C of pipeline A rather than refer to the latest.

Anyone?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Hi, what does "version" refer to ?

Comment: ok, sorted, it is the version of the artefact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current situation, we recommend you can follow the below request body to help you select your reference pipeline version.

```
{
    "stagesToSkip": [],
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/master"
            }
        },
        "pipelines": {
            "myresourcevars": {
                "version": "1313"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {}
}
```

Note: The name 'myresourcevars' is the pipeline name you defined in your yaml file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pBxn.png)